# Import libraries in Angular-Electron project

Tags: node.js, angular, requirejs, electron

I'm developing a web application using Angular 5.
I have wrapped it inside Electron because of I need to use the filesystem.

In order to use the node features I set the main.js file as follows:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 800,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
```

As you can see `nodeIntegration` is set to `true`.

With this configuration everything works well but I noticed that when I import some library in the .**angular-cli.json** file that libraries are not imported.

For example I import toastr as follows: (.angular-cli.json file)

```
"scripts": [
                "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
                "../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"
            ],
```

On the browser it works like a sharm, but in Electron I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: toastr is not defined
>   ReferenceError: toastr is not defined ...

How should I import an external library in order to make it works in Electron && Browser?

Thanks a lot

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm using `nodeIntegration: false` to make it works